# Trouble using python/brownie in WSL

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, windows-subsystem-for-linux, brownie

I'm trying to complete the simple collectible NFT tutorial from this [freeCodeCamp video](https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ?t=37098). (I'm getting stuck on the script that starts exactly where the link is timestamped to.)

For those that can't open the video, I'm trying to run this brownie command:

```
brownie run scripts/deploy_and_create.py --network rinkeby
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
dsine@DESKTOP-T74SG6U:/mnt/c/Users/dylan/projects/demos/nft-demo$ brownie run scripts/deploy_and_create.py --network rinkeby
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

NftDemoProject is the active project.
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 53, in run
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 149, in _import_from_path
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mnt.c.Users.dylan.projects'
```

I'm running this from the WSL Ubuntu terminal inside VSCode. I've tried running the script in powershell too. I've ensured I'm using Python 3 and WSL 2. I'm unsure of what is happening here.

Here is my deploy_and_create.py code:

```
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account
from brownie import SimpleCollectible

sample_token_uri = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmd9MCGtdVz2miNumBHDbvj8bigSgTwnr4SbyH6DNnpWdt?filename=0-PUG.json"
OPENSEA_URL = "https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/{}/{}"

def main():
    account = get_account()
    simple_collectible = SimpleCollectible.deploy({"from":account})
    tx = simple_collectible.createCollectible(sample_token_uri, {"from": account})
    tx.wait(1)
    print(f"Awesome, you can view your NFT at {OPENSEA_URL.format(simple_collectible.address, simple_collectible.tokenCounter() - 1)}")
    print("Please wait up to 20 minutes and hit the refresh metadata button.")
```

and my brownie-config.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0

compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'

dotenv: .env
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure but maybe this can help you to find solution! https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4377

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me like the issue stems from the function `_import_from_path` in the file brownie/project/scripts.py (that should be found in your eth-brownie folder, wherever you installed it). The way it is written, it will incorrectly identify Users.username as "not a module."

The solution: replace _import_from_path with the following

```
def _import_from_path(path: Path) -> ModuleType:
    # Imports a module from the given path
    
    import_str = "/" + "/".join(path.parts[1:-1] + (path.stem,))+'.py'
    
    if import_str in _import_cache:
        importlib.reload(_import_cache[import_str])
    else:
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('.'+path.stem,import_str)
        module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(module)
        _import_cache[import_str] = module
    return _import_cache[import_str]
```

Explanation: `import_str` is now modified to reflect the exact file location instead of a module name. The `else:` block now imports the module by specifying the file location and then loading that file as a module.

Comment: oo. This might be a good PR for the brownie repo if it's an issue with brownie itself. You think it's a brownie issue and not an issue from the persons setup?

Comment: It might :) that's just what I tackled in the past

Comment: This should definitely be tested on environments that don't have the problem. Something seems wrong in *\_import\_from\_path*, yet I can't figure out why it would behave differently on 2 systems.

Answer (score 1):

I had same troubles using WSL and I solved copying my project folder into "home".

You can do it using this command:

```
cp -R <source_folder> <destination_folder>
```

To make it clearer my implementation were this:

```
cp -R /mnt/c/users/macb/desktop/macb/personal/codigos/blockchain/brownie_simple_storage /home/martcerv
```

I recommend to navigate through your directories to know the paths you desire.